# How to find the name and address based on the mobile no in android?

Tags: android, service

When I am entering the mobile no I want to get details about mobile no like name of the owner, address and etc.

If any one has idea please help me.

Comment: Noone is understood your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously cannot stalk unknown phone numbers Kiran.

But yeah If the number is stored in your phonebook, check out this article on [how to use the contact API](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [truecallerjs] npm package

```
npm install -g truecallerjs
```

then login with Truecaller.

```
truecallerjs login
```

Searching a number

```
truecallerjs -s  [number]
```